# Rails 5 - redirect or render after downloading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

**Quick Summary** - Using `wicked_pdf` gem to generate a PDF. After generating a PDF, I would like to redirect to another page.

**My Code**

```
def show
 @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: "MyFile",
        template: 'forms/show.html.erb',
        disposition: 'attachment',
        locals: { f: @f },
        layout: 'pdf.html'
    end
  end
end
```

**Problem** - After the PDF gets downloaded, I cannot **redirect** to an action or **render** a view.

Since there can only be one HTTP response per request, what is another way to redirect **and** render?

Answer (score 1):

A hacky solution could be to have an onclick event on "Download pdf" anchor tag. The javascript can wait for few seconds (3 in below example) before taking user to another page

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url" }, 3000);
```

Anchor event-propagation will start pdf download immediately and browser will load new_url in 3 seconds.